# Discontinuous selection of Finder files by keyboard only

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, finder

I migrated from Windows to Mac very recently.

In Windows Explorer, once one or more files were selected, I could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd>/<kbd>DownArrow</kbd>
to hover over other files in the directory without deselecting the already selected files, then click <kbd>Space</kbd> to add the currently hovered file to the selection.
This allowed me to select discontinuous files in a directory by using only the keyboard.

I miss this feature. Trying all possible combinations of modifier keys, I figured it is not supported on Mac, and even the "hovering over files without selecting them" does not seem like a thing here.

Is this realization true? Is there a way to have somewhat similar functionality?
Thanks in advance for your ideas and opinions.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  I'd like to be proven wrong, of course, but I don't think it can be done natively. [30-years' Mac user]